# Installing Google js test for unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, v8

I am currently working on JavaScript and want to design unit test for JavaScript I am using google-JS-Test

http://code.google.com/p/google-js-test/

I have downloaded **gjstest-1.0.7**

I have installed all the prerequisites need.

http://code.google.com/p/google-js-test/wiki/Installing#Prerequisites

but when I install google js test using

```
$ cd gjstest-1.0.7 
$ make
```

I got following errors

```
g++ -DHASH_NAMESPACE=__gnu_cxx -lrt -I. -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DDEFAULT_DATA_DIR=/usr/local/share/gjstest  -c -o gjstest/internal/cpp/v8_utils.o gjstest/internal/cpp/v8_utils.cc
gjstest/internal/cpp/v8_utils.cc:33: error: ‘v8::StackFrame’ has not been declared
gjstest/internal/cpp/v8_utils.cc:34: error: ‘v8::StackTrace’ has not been declared
gjstest/internal/cpp/v8_utils.cc: In function ‘void gjstest::ConvertToStringVector(const v8::Handle<v8::Value>&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >*)’:
gjstest/internal/cpp/v8_utils.cc:60: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::Array::Get(uint32&)’
/usr/include/v8.h:1161: note: candidates are: v8::Local<v8::Value> v8::Object::Get(v8::Handle<v8::Value>)
make: *** [gjstest/internal/cpp/v8_utils.o] Error 1
```

It seems like v8 is not install correctly

I have installed V8 using commands like

```
sudo apt-get install libv8-2.0.3 
sudo apt-get install libv8-dbg 
sudo apt-get install libv8-dev
```

And also by downloading it

```
svn checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ v8
cd v8
make dependencies
scons
```

But still getting these errors

So if any one has installed and used Google Js or installed v8, kindly guide me on how should I solve this problem.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed caused by trying to build gjstest against a very old version of libv8.

I checked out and built a more recent libv8 on ubuntu 10.04 by following the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP):

```
svn checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ v8
cd v8
make depdendencies
make native library=shared
cp out/native/lib.target/libv8.so /usr/local/lib/libv8.so
cp include/v8.h /usr/local/include/v8.h
cp include/v8stdint.h /usr/local/include/v8stdint.h
```

After which gjstest compiled and ran without further surprises.